# How could I submit the Charge plugin using Ajax?

Tags: plugin-charge

I am using the [Charge](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge) plugin to handle my Stripe payments. How could I submit this form via Ajax Post and get the response? I have tried using the following code but it tells me it's a bad request:

```
this.ajaxReq = $.ajax({
   url: 'charge/charge',
   data: $('#charge-form').serialize()
}) .done(function(data) {
   console.log('success!');
   console.log(data);
}) .fail(function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Are you using the Stripe.js checkout option, as detailed in [the Charge documentation](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge/usage/quickstart/using-stripe-js)?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to modify the $form.get(0).submit(); that's part of jquery.charge so that this submission is sent via Ajax without a page refresh

Comment: Have you specified the `$.ajax` method? It uses `GET` by default, but you need to submit the form using `POST`.

Comment: You're welcome. I added my comment as an answer. If you can accept it, then we can close this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the HTTP method used by [the `$.ajax` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

By default, it uses `GET`, but you need to submit the form using `POST`.