# SquareBit Charge Plugin: How to retrieve error messages from failed ajax call?

Tags: plugins, error-message, ajax, plugin-charge

This is a continuation of [How could I submit the Charge plugin using Ajax?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20269/how-could-i-submit-the-charge-plugin-using-ajax)

I'm using the Charge plugin to handle my Stripe payments. I'm having to use ajax to submit the charge form before submitting a second form that is on the page. The problem is when the ajax call fails, I can't seem to get the error messages that are causing the failed attempt.

I'm pretty sure part of the reason is because I get a 404 every time it fails, because `'url: charge/charge'` path doesn't actually exist on my server. So, `console.log(data)` is basically useless to try and find how to access the error(s).

This is the code that I currently have:

```
this.ajaxReq = $.ajax({
  method: "post",
  url: 'charge/charge',
  data: $('#charge-form').serialize()
}) .done(function(data) {
    console.log('success');
}) .fail(function(data){
    console.log('failed');
    // Need to get error messages from Stripe/Charge?
});
```

Comment: Have you got the form working correctly _without_ AJAX, as per the instructions [on this page](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge/usage/quickstart/using-stripe-js)?

Comment: @StephenLewis Yes, I was able to get it working properly per the documentation. However, I'm needing to submit a freeform form whenever I submit the charge form, thus why I'm submitting via AJAX.

Comment: Well, if it works without AJAX, then the Charge route (`charge/charge`) must be working correctly. The Freeform stuff sounds rather convoluted, but I assume you have your reasons for doing it that way.